# Python way to automatically test interaction effects in OLS

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, linear-regression, patsy

In R you can essentially write `model='Lottery ~ (Literacy + Wealth + Region)^k'` and get every k-way combination of those variables.

`statsmodels` supports some R style OLS regressions but they don't seem to support the `^k` syntax. I have a large dataset, large enough where it is prohibitive to the practice of manually trying combinations of variables, and am essentially looking for a way to automate the interaction effect search.

Comment: great question. I'm sure you've looked at this : https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/example_formulas.html#multiplicative-interactions

Comment: @parsethis yes! That's actually part of why I decided to post. statsmodels doesn't have any documentation to indicate they support this functionality (I also tried a few different ways and got a syntax error), but I'm hoping that someone can either prove me wrong or point me in the direction of a package that does support this functionality, regardless of exact syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas are handled by `patsy` and not by statsmodels directly.

According to patsy documentation using power `(a + b + c + d) ** 3` works for interaction effects of categorical variables.

See section for `**` in https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html#the-formula-language

Aside: power in Python is `**` and not `^`